# Recursive Haskell; Newton's Method: Why Doesn't This Converge?

Tags: haskell, recursion, floating-point, calculus

I've been trying to learn Haskell by building short programs. I'm somewhat new to the functional programming world but have already done a good amount of reading.

I have a relatively short recursive function in Haskell for using Newton's method to find roots of a function up to the precision allowed by floating point numbers:

```
newtonsMethod :: (Ord a, Num a, Fractional a)  => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
newtonsMethod f f' x
    | f x < epsilon = x
    | otherwise = 
        newtonsMethod f f' (x - (f x / f' x))
    where
        epsilon = last . map (subtract 1) . takeWhile (/= 1) 
            . map (+ 1) . iterate (/2) $ 1
```

When I interpret in GHCi and plug in `newtonsMethod (\ x -> cos x + 0.2) (\ x -> -1 * sin x) (-1)`, I get `-1.8797716370899549`, which is the first iteration of Newton's method for the values called.

My first question is straightforward: why does it only recurse once? Please also let me know if you see any potential improvements to the way this code is structured or flagrant mistakes.

My second question, a little more involved, is this: is there some clean way to test parent calls of this function, see if it's failing to converge, and bail out accordingly?

Thanks in advance for any answer you can give!

Comment: Hopefully you do not use that function with an exact fractional type, where computation of `epsilon` would never end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It runs only once because `-1.8...` *is* less than `epsilon`, a strictly positive quantity. You want to check to see if the *absolute value* of the difference is within tolerance.

One way to get convergence diagnostics for this kind of code is to generate your results as a lazy list, not unlike how you found `epsilon` using `iterate`. That means that you can get your final result by traversing the list, but you can also see it in the context of the results that lead up to it.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't help re-writing it co-recursively and to use automatic differentiation. Of course one should really use the AD package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad. Then you don't have to calculate the derivative yourself and you can see the method converge.

```
data Dual = Dual Double Double
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

constD :: Double -> Dual
constD x = Dual x 0

idD :: Double -> Dual
idD x = Dual x 1.0

instance Num Dual where
  fromInteger n             = constD $ fromInteger n
  (Dual x x') + (Dual y y') = Dual (x + y) (x' + y')
  (Dual x x') * (Dual y y') = Dual (x * y) (x * y' + y * x')
  negate (Dual x x')        = Dual (negate x) (negate x')
  signum _                  = undefined
  abs _                     = undefined

instance Fractional Dual where
  fromRational p = constD $ fromRational p
  recip (Dual x x') = Dual (1.0 / x) (-x' / (x * x))

instance Floating Dual where
  pi = constD pi
  exp   (Dual x x') = Dual (exp x)   (x' * exp x)
  log   (Dual x x') = Dual (log x)   (x' / x)
  sqrt  (Dual x x') = Dual (sqrt x)  (x' / (2 * sqrt x))
  sin   (Dual x x') = Dual (sin x)   (x' * cos x)
  cos   (Dual x x') = Dual (cos x)   (x' * (- sin x))
  sinh  (Dual x x') = Dual (sinh x)  (x' * cosh x)
  cosh  (Dual x x') = Dual (cosh x)  (x' * sinh x)
  asin  (Dual x x') = Dual (asin x)  (x' / sqrt (1 - x*x))
  acos  (Dual x x') = Dual (acos x)  (x' / (-sqrt (1 - x*x)))
  atan  (Dual x x') = Dual (atan x)  (x' / (1 + x*x))
  asinh (Dual x x') = Dual (asinh x) (x' / sqrt (1 + x*x))
  acosh (Dual x x') = Dual (acosh x) (x' / (sqrt (x*x - 1)))
  atanh (Dual x x') = Dual (atanh x) (x' / (1 - x*x))

newtonsMethod' :: (Dual -> Dual) -> Double -> [Double]
newtonsMethod' f x = zs
  where
    zs  = x : map g zs
    g y = y - a / b
      where
        Dual a b = f $ idD y

epsilon :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a
epsilon = last . map (subtract 1) . takeWhile (/= 1) 
          . map (+ 1) . iterate (/2) $ 1
```

This gives the following

```
*Main> take 10 $ newtonsMethod' (\x -> cos x + 0.2) (-1)
[-1.0,
-1.8797716370899549,
-1.770515242616871,
-1.7721539749707398,
-1.7721542475852199,
-1.7721542475852274,
-1.7721542475852274,
-1.7721542475852274,
-1.7721542475852274,
-1.7721542475852274]
```

Comment: This is certainly above and beyond the scope of my question, but I very thoroughly appreciate it. You're the best!